# Вставить в contenteditable div изображение из буфера обмена

Tags: javascript, clipboard

Копирую изображение в буфер обмена, затем в contenteditable div нажимаю CTRL V - запускается следующий скрипт:

```
let el = document.getElementById("editabletext");

el.onpaste = function(event){
    let items = (event.clipboardData || event.originalEvent.clipboardData).items;

    let blob = null;
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (items[i].type.indexOf("image") === 0) {
            blob = items[i].getAsFile();
        }
    }
    // load image if there is a pasted image
    if (blob !== null) {
        let reader = new FileReader();


        reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
    }
```

После того, как отработает функция reader.readAsBinaryString(blob); изображение автоматически вставляется в div:

[image: ![введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема заключается в том, что после того, как изображение вставилось в div, я, получается, теряю над ним контроль, так как у него нет ни id, ни даже класса. А мне нужно еще разместить его по центру, изменить размер и прочее.

Можно ли как нибудь перед вставкой присвоить изображению id?

Comment: Создайте тег, а потом в `src` вставьте `base64`.

Comment: Я пытался так делать, но тогда у меня получалось два одинаковых изображения - первое, которое автоматически вставлялось функцией reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);, а второе - которое создавалось из тега <img id='pasted_img'>  путем присваивания src = base64 .

Удалить первое я не могу, так как у него нет id

Comment: Наверно можно из всех <img> на странице выбрать <img>, у которого отсутствует идентификатор и класс - это будет <img>, созданный автоматически...

Comment: А что нельзя просто прочитать, что что ты вставил через команду `ctrl+v`?

Comment: а ты уверен, что приведенный код работает? Ты пробовал комментировать `reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);`?

Comment: скорее всего, сейчас твой обработчик не влияет на вставку картинки. Однако ты можешь вызвать `event.preventDefault()` чтобы предотвратить стандартное поведение. Далее добавить обработчик `onload` для `reader` и внутри него самому создать элемент `img` с нужными атрибутами, установить ему `src` и вставить в документ

Comment: Да, все верно, не влияет. Спасибо. Попробую с event.preventDefault()